# Qt creator deleted files and is unrecoverable

Tags: qt, qt5, recover

I had a code which Qt deleted it by itself, now I cant recover it even with data recovery programs.

I dont know if qt caches codes anywhere or saves history of them, also i ran it couple of times so there are some `code.o` and `moc_code.cpp` but they dont seem any useful.

If you have any idea on how to recover it, please help.

Comment: I do not think that Qt deletes any code by itself. Add I do not think there is any way to recover it. Next time you should backup your work regularly or, even better, use version control system such s GIT or SVN or anything similar. This is the proper way of working with code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are a few things that you need to learn.

In general each development environment like Creator or Visual Studio will compile your code in one or more steps into something like an executable.

For Qt, the way roughly looks like this:

> .cpp/.hpp -> .moc -> .o -> executable

Files with suffix `.moc` or `.o` are generated by moc/gcc/msvc-compiler and whatever you edit inside them, is lost.

So I guess, you edited the moc file and these changes are definitely lost (unless you have a backup tool like TimeMachine which was fast enough to catch your edits before you compiled them away).

I recommend reading a step-by-step example and walk through that w/o deviating from the path that is given there. This should give you a better start.

Answer (score 0):

Qt will generate some code when compiling.
the .ui files will be used to generate xxx_ui.h files.
the .cpp/.h files may be used to generate xxx_moc.cpp files.
The auto generated files are not allowed to be modified.